# Installing a WCF service that does not have a MSI

Tags: wcf

I have developed a WCF service using .NET 3.5, VS 2010 on Win 7 64. This will be hosted in a Windows Service.
I created a Windows Service project to which an Installer is added by rt-clicking. The WCF dll is also added.

For testing purpose I have installed this service by running the InstallUtill.exe passing in the service exe from the Windows Service project release folder. All works fine I can see the service in Services.msc and they can be accessed by clients.

The client does not want an MSI so I have to give him the release folder of the Windows Service project.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it required to add the .NET framework requirement, which gets added by default for MSI projeccts, to the Windows Service project. If yes then how do I go about doing it?
2. Can the client use the InstallUtil.exe from the framework or is there another way to install on machines that don't have VS?
3. Does the service need to be built for both 32 and 64 bit systems?

I know that InstallUtil.exe is part of the framework and any machine that has one is good to go but just out of curiosity is there any other way to install the Windows service without an MSI?

Regards.

Comment: [How to create a Windows service by using Sc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about InstallUtil.exe, but I do know that in order to install a WCF service manually, you need to:

- Give the client the requirements (.NET framework, WCF installed)
- Create a folder in IIS for the service
- Create a bin folder in that folder
- Copy the .svc and the web.config in the first folder, and copy the .dll in the bin folder
- In IIS, right-click on the folders and Convert to application (the two folders)
- Be sure that the folders have the appropriate rights

I had to do this for test purposes on several machines at my job. But in the end, we did an MSI for the client.

Hope that helps you!